# PHP exec not working via crontab (cronjobs) but works fine via console

Tags: php, cron, exec

I try to restart my LTE modem via cron. I have a PHP file (restart.php) with exec() function:

```
exec('usb_modeswitch -R -v 12d1 -p 1436');
```

It works fine if I type in console (as root):

```
php restart.php
```

But not works via crontab (for root):

```
*/10 * * * * php /var/www/html/modem/restart.php
```

I have 777 permissions for restart.php file and the path is ok.

What is wrong? And how I can fix it? Any ideas?

Please, help

Comment: When you say "not works" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Is it reset.php or restart.php? Are you referencing the correct file in your crontab?

Comment: It's "restart.php". Sorry for mistake. When I say "not works" I mean nothing happened. My LTE modem had not been restarted and there is no error. I have a code after exec function and that code works

Comment: Try using the full path to the usb_modeswitch executable. Root may have a .profile or .bashrc file that sets up paths when you log in interactively but not in cron.

Comment: @RobRuchte, thank you so much! Working fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a full path to usb_modeswitch and it solved my problem:

```
exec('/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -R -v 12d1 -p 1436');
```

Rob Ruchte, Thank u for solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full path in crontab for php and in php script.
You can find where is php binary by this command:

```
whereis php
```